# 401 via Postman

Tags: alfresco, http-status-code-401

I am still have problem using some APIs. We are using Alfresco 7.1.1, and I'm using Postman to call some APIs.

For authentication, to get a ticket I am using
POST : https://xxx/alfresco/api/-default-/public/authentication/versions/1/tickets

The probleme is the next call using that ticket, and I receive a 401 response. Not all the time.

For exemple, to validate a ticket I use this API :
GET : https://xxx/alfresco/api/-default-/public/authentication/versions/1/tickets/-me-
with pm.request.headers.add("Authorization: Basic " + btoa("TICKET_xxx")); under the 'Pre-request Script' on Postman.

To delete a ticket, I use this
DELETE : https://xxx/alfresco/api/-default-/public/authentication/versions/1/tickets/-me-
with pm.request.headers.add("Authorization: Basic " + btoa("TICKET_xxx"));

When I call those API either to validate a ticket or to delete a ticket, sometimes it worked, sometimes I got 401.
Any idea why ?

Comment: I try it and you used this endpoints right. Alfresco return 401 if ticket is not valid. Are you sure that you call procedure in right order? And are you sure that you are not over session timeout?

Comment: Alfresco return 401 if ticket is not valid.  
-> Agree, the question is why. If the ticket is not valid, my next step would be to delete it. But, I got 401.  
  
Are you sure that you call procedure in right order? -> Yes, you need to get a ticket first. Once I have it, when I call to validate that ticket or to delete that ticket, 401 is returned.  
  
And are you sure that you are not over session timeout? -> I call the other APIs right after I have a ticket, so within seconds.